# Add string to string multiple times

Tags: python

How do I add content to a string multiple times?

```
import re

content = 'This is random text. I want to insert HELLO here --> "" and here too --> ""'

for text in re.finditer('""', content):
    start_index = text.start() + 1
    end_index = text.end() - 1

    content = content[:start_index] + 'HELLO' + content[end_index:]

print(content)
```

Unfortunately, the code above gives me following:

```
This is random text. I want to insert HELLO here --> "HELLO" and here too HELLO--> ""
```

Comment: You dont want to use 'replace' function?

Comment: Use str.replace or simply do the replacements in reverse order.

Comment: If you have another easier solution, please show me

Comment: @belismau you have some good answers so please accept one if it solves your problem. Or further clarify the problem if additional help is needed.

Answer (score 1):

How about `content.replace('""', '"HELLO"')` ?

Comment: I want to insert HELLO between ""

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you want :

```
string = ' geeks for geeks geeks geeks geeks' 
   
# Prints the string by replacing geeks by Geeks  
print(string.replace("geeks", '"Geeks"'))
```

The result is :

```
"Geeks" for "Geeks" "Geeks" "Geeks" "Geeks"
```